# How to avoid network call when REST client and server are on the same server

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, jersey, jax-rs

I have a web application in which two of the major components are the website (implemented in Groovy and Grails) and a backend RESTful web service (implemented using JAX-RS (Jersey) and Spring).  Both of these will be running in Glassfish.  The website will make calls to the RESTful web service.  In many cases, these components will reside on separate servers, so the website will make calls over the network to the RESTful web service.  If, however, I run both applications in the same Glassfish server, are there any optimizations that can be made to avoid the network call?  In other words, I'm looking for some equivalent of EJB's remote/local interfaces for REST.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't sweat the network call. Your traffic will generally never leave the local interface so you won't be consuming any bandwidth. You lose a bit of performance from serialization/deserialization, but you'll need to ask yourself if reducing the impact of this is worth developing a complicated proxy architecture. I think it most cases you'll find the answer to be no.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  This is what I suspected, but the confirmation really helps.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you will find any trivial solutions: you could of course add your own additional proxy layer, but I really wouldn't worry about it. Local network I/O (localhost or 127.0.0.1) is so heavily optimized anyway that you really won't notice.

Depending on your implementation Spring does support a number of remoting technologies (an old list is at http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/remoting.html), but you will find that key to all of these is the network transfer: they wrap it up in a variety of different ways but ultimately almost all turnkey remoting technologies drop into the network at some point in time. You may gain SOME efficiency by not having to use HTTP, but you will probably lose some of the loose coupling you gained by using Jersey.

If you are not too afraid to tightly couple maybe you can put the actual objects you are exposing via Jersey into a Glassfish-wide Spring context and invoke the methods directly: much tighter coupling though, so I'd say stick with the HTTP calls.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can avoid a network call if your server and client both reside in the same JVM. You should be able to use Jersey Client API to create your own implementation of Connector to override default HTTP calls and handle request/response. Here is the blog that can get you started - http://www.theotherian.com/2013/08/jersey-2.0-server-side-client-in-memory-connector.html

IMHO, an unnecessary network overhead should be avoided at all cost. Even though this overhead would be only a few milliseconds, but while building features for your web application, you would increase such services call and all these milliseconds will add up to a good amount of latency on your application.